# upgrade from Lubuntu 13.04 to 13.10 failed and system doesn,t boot

Tags: installation, upgrade

I tried to upgrade lubuntu 13.04 to 13.10 using Software Update Manager and received several errors during upgrade process. I received massage thant upgrade failed and the systen sent a bug report. After re-booting i receive a screen with these options
Ubundu 
ubuntu advaned options 
....

I tried all options. nothing works. the system does not boot,
fsck and mount all give nothning

please help. I am afraid i have lost my file system

Answer (score 1):

Had exactly the same problem, nothing was helping, don't worry, your files won't be deleted (even if they are encrypted) just calm down and

Try this:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

even my previously opened tabs in chromium were not closed :)

Answer (score 1):

look guys I don't know it's bug or what but you can't upgrade your UBUNTU . 
since UBUNTU 10.10 I've been trying to upgrade through software updater or ... but none of them worked for me I asked from some pro about it they said don't tired your self it won't work just download the new version ISO file and boot it and format your Linux partition and install from 0 . this is a way that every time I use to upgrade .

there is another way to upgrade . 
boot live version of UBUNTU and go through installation steps then in the part that you should decide to format or install alongside windows or .... choose to upgrade your older UBUNTU this way worked for me once .

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me also. The only way I could get through this this was reinstalling Ubuntu, not upgrading it.

Go to http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop, download the one you want and install over your current Ubuntu.